# SendMessage() to win32 application vc++

Tags: winapi

I have a win32 application project. but when the program get to a place like
let's say new_socket = accept(socket, (sockaddr *)&client, &c); 
it get stuck. in these kind of scripts it makes me unable to use any other button, file menu and etc. is anybody that can tell me what is wrong and how am going to fix it.

this is the function where it get stuck:

```
void server(){
    WSADATA wsa;
    SOCKET server_socket, client_socket;
    struct sockaddr_in server, client;
    int c, yes=1;
    int sent_length = 1;

    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0) printf("Failed. Error Code : %d",WSAGetLastError());

    if((server_socket = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0 )) == INVALID_SOCKET){
        printf("Could not create socket : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
    }

    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = 0;
    server.sin_port = htons(8080);
    memset(&(server.sin_zero), '\0', 8);

    bind(server_socket ,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server));

    listen(server_socket, 3);
    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    while(1){
        client_socket = accept(server_socket,(struct sockaddr *)&client, &c);
        send(client_socket, "Hello, World", 13, 0);
       }

    WSACleanup();
}
```

Comment: Where's the hidden link between the title and the question?

Answer (score 1):

accept is syncronous call and not return, until client connect. this mast not be used in GUI thread. need or do this call in another thread or (the best) use only asynchronous api (AcceptEx)

Comment: thanks for you response, but I think I figured a way out for that but now there is a new problem which I am faced with, can you tell me how to send data over the network. I did used send() function but it didn't worked